# Is there a length limit in the replaceWhere clause string?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I was wondering if there is a length/size limit in terms of characters for a replaceWhere clause. I am writing some automatically-generated replaceWhere clauses and I fear that some of them might be too long.

I could not find anything on the official Spark documentation.

Comment: Does your table/external location have a lot of partitions to cause the replaceWhere to be that big? If you have specific updates to execute, maybe it would be best to use `MERGE INTO`.

Comment: @KevinBarranco Thanks for the suggestion, but I am still interested in knowing the limitations of the approach I'm using.

Comment: Yes exists, i'm not sure what is length but could be potential issue with catalyst stage while generate physical plan.